# How to make the RESTful resources in jersey support HTTPS

Tags: java, rest, https, jersey

I have a server and client pair. Server is written in java using Jersey for RESTful APIs. I am running it in Tomcat server. It is working fine for HTTP GET/POST/DELETE calls. But I want to make the calls using HTTPS. What do I need to change on server side?

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
@Path("/article")
public class ArticleService {

EntityDao<Article> articleDao = new ArticleDaoImpl();

@GET
public Response greet() {
    return Response.ok("Welcome to restroshop APIs...").build();
}

@GET
@Path("/read/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response readArticle(@PathParam("id") final long id) {

    Article article = articleDao.read(id);
    return article != null ?
            Response.ok(article, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build() :
            Response.noContent().build();
}

@POST
@Path("/create")
public long create(Article article) {
    return ((Long) articleDao.create(article));
}

@DELETE
@Path("/delete/{id}")
public Response delete(@PathParam("id") final long id) {
    articleDao.delete(id);
    return Response.ok("Article Deleted successfully").build();
}
}
```

My web.xml is as following:

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Restroshop Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Restroshop-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.restroshop.application</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Restroshop-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My Client is an android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of what you've shown, none of your code needs to change.  But to enable SSL depends on your setup.  If you've got Apache httpd in front of Tomcat, then you'll need to start with [the Apache SSL docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html).  If you're running only Tomcat then you'll need to take a look at [the Tomcat SSL docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).  Both of these processes are very well documented.

Comment: I followed steps given in Tomcat SSL docs, but don't know how to import certificate into chrome. There is no .cert file generated which chrome asks for while importing.